# How to fix NameError When I call a function from another file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, nameerror, undetected-chromedriver

I wanted to log in to Gmail using selenium and undetected_chromedriver. Successfully logged in using these codes. My gmail_login.py files codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

if __name__ == '__main__':

        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-error")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
        # e.g. Chrome path in Mac =/Users/x/Library/xx/Chrome/Default/
        # options.add_argument( "--user-data-dir=<Your chrome profile>")
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        url='https://accounts.google.com/servicelogin'
        driver.get(url)
        # add email
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(gmail_uid)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/span').click()
       
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(gmail_pwd)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/span').click()
       

        def my_custom_function(url):

                get_url = driver.get(url)

                return get_url
```

But When I am trying to call my `my_custom_function(url)` from a different python file, Got `NameError`. My new_file.py looks like

```
from gmail_login import *

print(my_custom_function('https://google.com')) 

NameError: name 'my_custom_function' is not defined
```

I am assuming this `NameError` raise for this `if __name__ == '__main__':` indentation

How can I solve this? Both of the files are in same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Using `if __name__ == "__main__":` provides an entrypoint for your project and usually used when you have multiple files and want to specify what will happen when you run the project.

For further reading: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/

So all the code, variable and function (as in your case my_custom_function) declarations are run once the gmail_login.py file is executed. That's why it says it is not defined.
What to do? You could define your function above if statement and then call it in if statement and import wherever you want. Hope it helps!

Shortly refactoring your code as how i would do as an example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

def get_driver():
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-error")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
        # e.g. Chrome path in Mac =/Users/x/Library/xx/Chrome/Default/
        # options.add_argument( "--user-data-dir=<Your chrome profile>")
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        url='https://accounts.google.com/servicelogin'
        driver.get(url)
        # add email
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(gmail_uid)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/span').click()
       
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(gmail_pwd)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/span').click()

        return driver

def my_custom_function(url):
        driver = get_driver()
        get_url = driver.get(url)

        return get_url

if __name__ == "__main__":
        my_custom_function()
```

Comment: Could you please give a example code where I can use

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example. Please keep in mind that the logic in the example might not serve your desire. You might need to update your logic with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your input but unfortunately it's not working for me.